# Is it ok to assign all variables to an object for a way to avoid creating global variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.For example if i had defined an object before declaring the variables, then called the them as part of the object as below...

```
//Global object
var Global = [];

//Every var thereafter ...
Global.variable1 = some value;
Global.variable2 = some value;
Global.variable3 = some value;**
```

Comment: It's not just okay, it's recommended. However, JavaScript uses `{}` to create an object; `[]` is a linear array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called `namespacing`.  It creates a single global (which should probably have a more unique name than you are using) and then puts all your global state as a property on that single global.

This is a well used and recommended practice, used by libraries such as jQuery that are designed to be compatible with lots of other code (that may have its own globals).  This practice limits the use of your own globals which lessens the chance of conflict with other code.

You would generally make the single global be an `Object`, not an array like this:

```
var myGlobal = {};
myGlobal.prop1 = "whatever";
```

---

There are other ways to limit how many variables must truly be global by using a closure to enclose both your code and your state.  This is an alternate technique to the `namespacing` that you proposed.

It works like this:

```
(function() {
    var variable1 = some value;
    var variable2 = some value;
    var variable3 = some value;

    // all your code here that uses variable1, variable2 and variable3
})();
```

These variables are actually local variables to the **immediately invoked function expression** (abbreviated IIFE which is essentially just an anonymous function that is immediately executed for the purpose of creating a function scope that has private variables).

Because all your code is in the same function scope, they work like globals for your code without actually being globals.  Other code cannot conflict with these variables or access these variables so it also achieves privacy.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reason's people use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression ([IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)). By putting your code in an anonymous function that calls itself, you don't have to worry about variables polluting the global namespace.

It looks something like this:

```
(function() {
    var variable1 = 'some value'; // This variable is not global
    var variable2 = 'some value'; // This variable is not global
    var variable3 = 'some value'; // This variable is not global
})();
```